# Doing a background task in android when app is closed or phone in doze mode

Tags: android, backgroundworker, android-workmanager

I want to do an http request each day and showing a notification based on the http response.

I tried to use any option but nothing really works.

I am testing my app on Oneplus 3T android 8.1

I tried to use `AlarmManager` with the following methods `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle` and `setAlarmClock` but those methods sometimes firing and sometimes isn't and I don't understand why they aren't persistent. From what I read from Android 8 `AlarmManager` ins't persistent because the Doze Mode.

I then tried to use `WorkManager` with `OneTimeWorkRequest` but this solution get killed when I closing my app but, when I set my app to not be optimized by the phone the `WorkManager` keeps running even if I closing my app.

I want to find a solution that does work in any situation (Doze mode, app closed, etc) and isn't requiring to ask the user to remove my app from the phone's battery optimization. I know that it is possible because I have apps that show me notifications when I receive a new massage like Instagram, Facebook, Gmail etc (from what I understand those apps using `FCM` to do so but I am not sure about that and if they are I am not going to use Firebase only for that)

I searched for a solution for four days long and didn't find anything.

Comment: Is there a reason you couldn't use a background service that calls WorkManager?

Comment: I tried it but my phone is still killing it